# Calling Terms and Conditions in Swift / Xcode on first load

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have set up an application with two ViewControllers:

1) *Terms and Conditions* screen

2) *General welcome* screen.

I want my app to show the Terms and Conditions ViewController on startup as long as the user hasn't accepted the terms yet.

Once accepted, the general welcome screen should be the first loaded ViewController in the cycle. How can I manage this?

Comment: Keep a value on `UserDefaults`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you view the terms save a bool value in userDefaults say it's `termsViewed` and check it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to trigger direct navigate to welcome screen

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "termsViewed")
    { 
        let stor = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let welcomeView = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeID")

        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeView )

        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true

       self.window?.rootViewController = nav

    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you!

First I created a button on the 'Terms and Conditions' page. I connected this button to an TouchUpInside action, which contained:

UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "termsViewed")